# Rails Argument Error on .save - Something to do with has_many belongs_to in Model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, migration, relational-database, runtime-error

I get the following error when trying to save an entry into my database:

`ArgumentError: Unknown key: class`

This happens when I try to define which `PageIcon` my `Page` model belongs to.

---

Page Migration:

```
class CreatePages < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :pages do |t|
      t.integer "parent_page_id"
      t.integer "page_image_id", :null => false
      t.integer "page_icon_id"
      t.integer "template_id"

      t.string "title", :null => false
      t.string "path", :default => "", :null => false
      t.string "group"
      t.datetime "deleted_at"
      t.boolean "visible", :default => false

      t.timestamps
    end
    add_index("pages", "parent_page_id")
    add_index("pages", "page_image_id")
    add_index("pages", "page_icon_id")
    add_index("pages", "template_id")
    add_index("pages", "title")
    add_index("pages", "path")
  end
end
```

Page Model:

```
class Page < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :parent, :class_name => 'Page', :foreign_key => 'parent_page_id'
  has_many :children, :class_name => 'Page', :foreign_key => 'parent_page_id'
  belongs_to :page_image, :class_name => 'Image', :foreign_key => 'page_image_id'
  has_many :sections
  has_many :attributes
  belongs_to :page_icon, :class_name => 'PageIcon', :foreign_key => 'page_icon_id'

  validates_uniqueness_of :title, :case_sensitive => false
end
```

---

PageIcon Migration

```
class CreatePageIcons < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :page_icons do |t|
      t.string 'title', :null => false
      t.string 'description'
      t.string 'url', :null => false
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

PageIcon Model:

```
class PageIcon < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :pages, :class_name => 'Page', :foreign_key => 'page_icon_id'
end
```

---

When I enter the following into rails console I get the error:

```
p = Page.find(1)
p.page_icon = PageIcon.find(1)
p.save
```

Error:
`ArgumentError: Unknown key: class`

---

Full log:

```
1.9.3-p392 :001 > p = Page.find(4)
  Page Load (0.8ms)  SELECT `pages`.* FROM `pages` WHERE `pages`.`id` = 4 LIMIT 1
 => #<Page id: 4, parent_page_id: nil, page_image_id: 1, page_icon_id: nil, template_id: nil, title: "Food", path: "", group: nil, deleted_at: nil, visible: true, created_at: "2013-03-29 12:21:31", updated_at: "2013-03-29 12:21:31"> 
1.9.3-p392 :002 > p.page_icon = PageIcon.find(2)
  PageIcon Load (0.3ms)  SELECT `page_icons`.* FROM `page_icons` WHERE `page_icons`.`id` = 2 LIMIT 1
 => #<PageIcon id: 2, title: "Food", description: nil, url: "page_icons/food.svg", created_at: "2013-03-30 01:37:13", updated_at: "2013-03-30 01:37:13"> 
1.9.3-p392 :003 > p.save
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
  Page Exists (0.5ms)  SELECT 1 AS one FROM `pages` WHERE (`pages`.`title` = 'Food' AND `pages`.`id` != 4) LIMIT 1
   (0.2ms)  ROLLBACK
ArgumentError: Unknown key: class
    from /Users/RyanKing/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activesupport-3.2.12/lib/active_support/core_ext/hash/keys.rb:51:in `block in assert_valid_keys'
    from /Users/RyanKing/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activesupport-3.2.12/lib/active_support/core_ext/hash/keys.rb:50:in `each_key'
    from /Users/RyanKing/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activesupport-3.2.12/lib/active_support/core_ext/hash/keys.rb:50:in `assert_valid_keys'
    from /Users/RyanKing/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activerecord-3.2.12/lib/active_record/associations/builder/association.rb:33:in `validate_options'
    from /Users/RyanKing/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activerecord-3.2.12/lib/active_record/associations/builder/association.rb:24:in `build'
    from /Users/RyanKing/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activerecord-3.2.12/lib/active_record/autosave_association.rb:139:in `build'
    from /Users/RyanKing/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activerecord-3.2.12/lib/active_record/associations/builder/belongs_to.rb:14:in `build'
    from /Users/RyanKing/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activerecord-3.2.12/lib/active_record/associations/builder/association.rb:12:in `build'
    from /Users/RyanKing/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activerecord-3.2.12/lib/active_record/associations.rb:1431:in `belongs_to'
    from /Users/RyanKing/Sites/gastromica/app/models/attribute.rb:3:in `<class:Attribute>'
    from /Users/RyanKing/Sites/gastromica/app/models/attribute.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/RyanKing/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activesupport-3.2.12/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:469:in `load'
    from /Users/RyanKing/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activesupport-3.2.12/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:469:in `block in load_file'
    from /Users/RyanKing/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activesupport-3.2.12/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:639:in `new_constants_in'
    from /Users/RyanKing/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activesupport-3.2.12/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:468:in `load_file'
    from /Users/RyanKing/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activesupport-3.2.12/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:353:in `require_or_load'
... 35 levels...
    from /Users/RyanKing/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activerecord-3.2.12/lib/active_record/validations.rb:50:in `save'
    from /Users/RyanKing/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activerecord-3.2.12/lib/active_record/attribute_methods/dirty.rb:22:in `save'
    from /Users/RyanKing/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activerecord-3.2.12/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:259:in `block (2 levels) in save'
    from /Users/RyanKing/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activerecord-3.2.12/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:313:in `block in with_transaction_returning_status'
    from /Users/RyanKing/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activerecord-3.2.12/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:192:in `transaction'
    from /Users/RyanKing/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activerecord-3.2.12/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:208:in `transaction'
    from /Users/RyanKing/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activerecord-3.2.12/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:311:in `with_transaction_returning_status'
    from /Users/RyanKing/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activerecord-3.2.12/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:259:in `block in save'
    from /Users/RyanKing/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activerecord-3.2.12/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:270:in `rollback_active_record_state!'
    from /Users/RyanKing/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activerecord-3.2.12/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:258:in `save'
    from (irb):3
    from /Users/RyanKing/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:47:in `start'
    from /Users/RyanKing/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:8:in `start'
    from /Users/RyanKing/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/commands.rb:41:in `<top (required)>'
    from script/rails:6:in `require'
    from script/rails:6:in `<main>'1.9.3-p392 :004 >
```

---

When I remove the `has_many` and `belongs_to` relationships between the `Page` & `PageIcons` models everything works fine again. Does anyone know what going on here? As far as I can tell the syntax is correct.

---

UPDATE

Attribute is reserved word in rails as pointed out here: http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/2722528

So changing `has_many :attributes` to `has_many :page_attributes, class_name="Attribute"` in the `Page` model does the trick.

Comment: I have tested this and it seems to be working fine, so I assume the problem is not on the Page or PageIcon models. The error log alo mentions '/app/models/attribute.rb' -- what do you have in there?

Comment: Thanks I had accidently written :call instead of :class_name in attributes.rb - I now get the error in return: `undefined method `keys' for []:ActiveRecord::Relation`

Comment: Go it! Attribute is reserved word in rails as pointed out here: http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/2722528  - Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Attribute is reserved word in rails as pointed out here: http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/2722528

So changing `has_many :attributes` to `has_many :page_attributes, class_name="Attribute"` in the `Page` model does the trick.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need the `:class_name` nor the `:foreign_key` hashes at all. Your relationships are set up the standard way, so those hashes are superfluous.

Comment: Yeah they exist just as a result of error checking - the error still occurs otherwise.

Comment: The only thing that jumps out at me is an absence of `attr_accessible` on any of the models. What happens if you add them in?

Comment: Nah `attr_accessible` doesn't help, sorry.